# Knockout custom click binding, return true to prevent click hijack?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

So we all know `return true` manually will allow default click action on element with a `click` binding, but what if I have custom binding as following:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.action = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var options = valueAccessor();
        var params = options.slice(1);

        //wrap it in function, with parameter binding
        var newValueAccessor = function() {
            return function() {
                options[0].apply(context, params);
            };
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.click.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    }
};
```

which takes N arguments from a binding:

```
action: [handle, 'open', $index()]
```

how does one allow click to go through? `return true` in `handle` does not work in this case.

Comment: I suppose my question would be, why do you want to allow the click to go through?

Comment: we don't all know that - I always assumed that returning false would cancel but returning void wouldn't prevent the default action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual click handler is defined here:

```
        return function() {
            options[0].apply(context, params);
        };
```

Just change it so it returns the value of the provided sub-handler:

```
        return function() {
            return options[0].apply(context, params);
        };
```